# angular / Jquery Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, translation

I'm working on angular project and I'm sorting my data into a  datatable, it's initialized in a js file like that :

```
    $(function () {
        $('#sorting-table').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ par page",
                "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                "info": "Page _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Aucun résultat trouvé",
                "zeroRecords": "Rien trouvé - Désolé",
                "search": "Chercher",
                "infoFiltered": "(total: _MAX_ )",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "Précédent",
                    "next": "Suivant"
                }
            },
            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 10, 15, -1],
                [5, 10, 15, "Tous"]
            ],
            "order": [
                [0, "desc"]
            ],
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: {
                buttons: [{
                    attr: { id: 'printButton' },
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="la la-print"></i>',
                    title: $('h1').text(),
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3]
                    },
                    footer: true,
                    autoPrint: true,
                }],
                dom: {
                    container: {
                        className: 'dt-buttons'
                    },
                    button: {
                        className: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });


})(jQuery);
```

On a component that my table is sorted I want to work with angular ngx-translation, if the current language change I want to change the language of my data table !

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      if (this.translate.currentLang === 'ar') {
        $('#sorting-table').DataTable({
          language: {
            url: 'cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Arabic.json'
          }
        });
      }
    })
}
```

I got this error :

> DataTables warning: table id=sorting-table - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Have you explored alternatives to jQuery?

Comment: no, I'm allowed to use it in this project

Comment: Did you visit the URL in the error?

Answer (score 0):

url should be like this : //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20

and add destroy:true